# FileOpenPicker without Camera

Tags: c#, camera, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, fileopenpicker

Is there a way to use Windows Phone 8.1 (RT) `FileOpenPicker` to select an image from the pictures library without offering to use the camera?

```
FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
openPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
openPicker.PickSingleFileAndContinue();
```

Above code opens an image picker view with images from the library and a camera button on the bottom. Can that camera button be removed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To provide a consistent user experience in the file picker, when you add an image based file filter as you have done by specifying `.jpg`, the camera button is added as a convenience.

It cannot be removed.

Comment: Fact or opinion? Meaning: is that officially stated somewhere? Could otherwise just be a limitation if it is in fact not available. User experience now is that this sucker occasionally crashes.

Comment: Why do you want to disable it?

Comment: Fact. It's added based on file extension you selected. Sure, they could always add a new feature to disable the button. But, they haven't. I'm not sure what your crashes are related to.

Comment: I'm afraid discussing motives will quickly drive the discussion off-topic. Let's say the button is not needed/useful in the app. The crash could be the subject of a new question. As it happens while the app itself is suspended, I'm a bit pessimistic.

Comment: The cause of the app crashing is very likely do to no or not functional implementation of application suspension, look into that and the presence of camera button will be a great new feature instead of an issue.